Equality of two functions if their integral is equal
I'm reading "Mathmatical Introduction" chapter of "Principles of Quantum Mechanics" by R. Shankar, and Exercise 1.10.3 says

Consider the theta function $\theta(x-x')$ which vanishes if $x-x'$ is negative and equals 1 if $x-x'$ is positive. Show that $\delta(x-x')=d/dx\ \theta(x-x')$

I tried following solution
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\theta'(x-x')dx&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)d(\theta(x-x'))\\
&=\left.f(x)\theta(x-x')\right|_{-\infty}^\infty + \int_{x'}^\infty f'(x)dx'\\
&=f(\infty)-f(\infty)+f(x') = f(x')\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta(x-x')dx\tag{$\delta(x)=\delta(-x)$}
\end{align*}
$$
So can I conclude from here that the delta and derivative of theta functions are equal? I do not think I can, if I can can you tell me why? If I can't then can you tell me how to proceed with the solution?

Might just be an artifact of copy/paste, but it seems to me that d/dx θ(x−x′) is incorrect, and should instead be dθ(x−x′)/dx . Or d(θ(x−x′))/dx to be more explicit.

There were a few errors in the analysis.  The derivative of $\theta$ does not exist in the ordinary sense.  It can be interpreted either as a distribution or as a measure.

We can interpret $\theta'$ as a measure using the Riemann-Stieltjes integral.
Let $f\in C_C^\infty$.  Then, we have
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)d\theta(x-x')&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\left(f(x)\theta(x-x')\right)-\int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x)\theta(x-x')\,dx\\\\
&=\left.\left(f(x)\theta(x-x')\right)\right|_{-\infty}^\infty-\int_{x'}^\infty f'(x)\,dx\\\\
&=f(x')
\end{align}$$
since $f$ is of compact support (i.e., it vanishes outside a closed set).
So as a measure $\theta'$ is identical to the Dirac Delta.

We can interpret $\theta'$ as a distribution.  We define the derivative $d'$ of a distribution $d$ such that for any $f\in C_C^\infty$, we have
$$\langle d',f\rangle =-\langle d,f\rangle$$
Thus if $d'=\theta_{x'}$, we find that
$$-\langle d',f\rangle =f(x')$$
Inasmuch as $\langle \delta_{x'},f\rangle =f(x')$, then in distribution $\delta_{x'}=\theta'(x-x')$.

I see. Thank you for the answer.

Of course.   You're welcome.  My pleasure

Hi Mark ! Best wishes for you and your family. Happy New Year !!

@ClaudeLeibovici Hi Claude, my friend!!  Happy Holidays and Happy New Year to you and yours too!!
